# Write pandas Dataframe to Dynamo DB table with data types intact

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Pandas Dataframe, which looks like below:

```html
A      B     C
Yes   25     35
No    65     54
Yes   53     98
```

In this data frame:

Column A being of data type - String

Column B being of data type - Float64

Column C being of data type - Float64

I want to upload this Data Frame into the Dynamo DB table in a way that I do not need to convert all the values as strings but keep strings as strings and convert float64 into number or decimal( Which is acceptable by Dynamo DB).

I used this code till now to convert all the values into a string( df being the data frame), before writing the same to the dynamo db table :

```py
for i in df.columns:
    
        print(i)
        print(df[i].dtypes)
        
        datatype = df[i].dtype
        df = df.fillna(0)
        if datatype == 'float64':
            print('yes')
            df[i] = df[i].astype(int)
```

How can I achieve the desired output? Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: There won't be `NaNs` in your `float64` columns?

Comment: Hi , I think i would handle the nan values with the below command:   df1 = df1.replace(np.nan, " ", regex=True)

Comment: So NaNs wunt be a  probelm